# MvxRecycleView selected item background

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

How can I set selected item background in MvxRecycleView?

I want to change background of selected item while another.

selector_category_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item  android:state_pressed="true"  android:state_enabled="true"  >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        </shape>
            </item>

    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_enabled="true"  >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/grayBackground"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

My MvxRecycleView

```
<MvxRecyclerView
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:background="#e2e2e2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/category_item"
            local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Categories; ItemClick SelectCategoryCommand; SelectedItem SelectedCategory"
            android:id="@+id/categoryRecyclerView" />
```

And category_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_category_item"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ffimageloading.cross.MvxCachedImageView
            android:id="@+id/categoryImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            local:MvxBind="DrawableName CategoryImage" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/favIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:src="@drawable/no_fav_icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/categoryText"
        style="@style/TextStyleBlack"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
        android:letterSpacing="-0.04"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="0sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        local:MvxBind="Text Name"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I need change selected item background to other while item is selected. 
How can I sort it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a custom MvxRecyclerView adapter to handle selection:

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter : MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerAdapter
{
    public MyRecyclerAdapter(IMvxAndroidBindingContext bindingContext) : base(bindingContext)
    {
    }

    public MyRecyclerAdapter(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        base.OnBindViewHolder(holder, position);
        holder.ItemView.Selected = _selectedPosition == position;
        holder.ItemView.Click += (s, e) => SelectIndex(holder.AdapterPosition);
    }

    private void SelectIndex(int index)
    {
        NotifyItemChanged(_selectedPosition);
        _selectedPosition = index;
        NotifyItemChanged(_selectedPosition);
    }

    private int _selectedPosition = RecyclerView.NoPosition;
}
```

Then you want to set the `MvxRecyclerView.Adapter` property somewhere in your view. The ideal place is usually `OnCreate` for an activity, or `OnCreateView` for a fragment:

`recyclerView.Adapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter((IMvxAndroidBindingContext)BindingContext);`

At this point you have a RecyclerView which sets the item you click on as selected. Now you can use a ColorStateList to change the color depending on the selection state. Add the file to Resources\drawable\selector_category_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item 
    android:drawable="@color/colorAccent"
    android:state_pressed="true" />
  <item 
    android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:state_selected="true" />
</selector>
```

Finally set the background of the category_item.xml `LinearLayout` to:

```
android:background="@drawable/selector_category_item"
```

It's worth pointing out you can also use a different ColorStateList to change the `android:textColor` as desired based on the selection state as well. You just need to put those ColorStateList XML files in the Resources\color folder instead of Resources\drawable.

I posted a working sample on [GitHub](https://github.com/tbalcom/MvxRecyclerViewSelection/).

Comment: Where or how should SelectIndex(int index) called?

Comment: SelectIndex shows how to programmatically select an item in the RecyclerView adapter by index. It's useful if you wanted to select an item in the View from the ViewModel for example. If you only care about selecting the last clicked item then you don't need the SelectIndex method. I included it to show you should call `NotifyItemChanged` for both the old and new selection when programmatically selecting an item.

Comment: I see, I've implemented ur part of code and it doesn't work. If I set breakpoint on    holder.ItemView.Selected = _selectedPosition == position; and set _selectedPosition value equals position  that work, any other clicks - nope.

Comment: I've edited the post with a slightly modified MyRecyclerAdapter which selects the most recently clicked item. The previous example would set the `Selected` property correctly but the calls to `NotifyItemChanged` were missing so you didn't see an update in the UI after clicking.

Comment: Hi Trevor. Thanks for your help.  I've implemented ur changes, and, u know, it blinking when I click on item, but color isn't fixed.

Comment: If you're using the original selector you posted then that is probably the problem. You don't have a color for `android:state_selected`.

Comment: No, I copied selector which you has provided to me. And it just blinking

Answer (score 0):

1. Make boolean flag to save selected state for each category item on `Category model`.
2. On your adapter `viewHolder` make instance for recycler item root view `mBackground`.
3. On `onBindViewHolder` update `mBackground` selection status.

   ```
   class MyDataHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
       implements View
       .OnClickListener {
   LinearLayout mBackground;
   MyDataHolder(View itemView) {
       super(itemView);
       mBackground = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_item_root_view);
       itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
   }



   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(MyCategoryAdapter.MyDataHolder holder, int position) {
       final Category category = getItem(position);
       holder.mBackground.setSelected(category.isSelected());
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks. Maybe this acceptable for android, but not working for Xamarin.